# How to set time zone of values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I'd like to set the time zone of the values of a column in a Pandas DataFrame. I am reading the DataFrame with pandas.read_csv().

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can read dates as UTC directly from [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv) by setting the `date_parser` function manually, for example:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
from dateutil.parser import parse

def date_utc(s):
    return parse(s, tzinfos=tzutc)

df = read_csv('my.csv', parse_dates=[0], date_parser=date_utc)
```

.

If you are creating a timeseries, you can use the `tz` argument of `date_range`:

```
dd = pd.date_range('2012-1-1 1:30', periods=3, freq='min', tz='UTC')

In [2]: dd
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-01 01:30:00, ..., 2012-01-01 01:32:00]
Length: 3, Freq: T, Timezone: UTC
```

.

If your DataFrame/Series is already index by a timeseries, you can use the [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tz_localize.html#pandas.DataFrame.tz_localize) method to set a timezone:

```
df.tz_localize('UTC')
```

or if it already has a timezone, use [`tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert.html#pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert):

```
df.tz_convert('UTC')
```

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I am actually reading the DataFrame with pandas.read_csv().

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize my example was misleading until you answered.

Comment: That's ok, I hope this now answers your question :)

Answer (score 15):

```
# core modules
from datetime import timezone, datetime

# 3rd party modules
import pandas as pd
import pytz

# create a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime(2018, 12, 30, 20 + i, 56)
                            for i in range(2)]},)
print(df)

# Convert the time to a timezone-aware datetime object
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(timezone.utc)
print(df)

# Convert the time from to another timezone
# The point in time does not change, only the associated timezone
my_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_convert(my_timezone)
print(df)
```

gives

```
                 date
0 2018-12-30 20:56:00
1 2018-12-30 21:56:00
                       date
0 2018-12-30 20:56:00+00:00
1 2018-12-30 21:56:00+00:00
                       date
0 2018-12-30 21:56:00+01:00
1 2018-12-30 22:56:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')

This seems to work starting with my 'naive' timezone.