# Updating a transaction time data frame to be 4 hours earlier

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, datetime-conversion

Currently I have a working dataframe exporter that exports stock transactions into a CSV file

```
activities = api.get_activities(
    date='2021-03-22',
    direction='asc',
)

df = pd.DataFrame([activity._raw for activity in activities])
print('')
print('=====Created The Dataframe=====')

id = df["id"]
activity_type = df["activity_type"]
transaction_time = df["transaction_time"]
type = df["type"]
price = df["price"]
qty = df["qty"]
side = df["side"]
symbol = df["symbol"]
leaves_qty = df["leaves_qty"]
order_id = df["order_id"]
cum_qty = df["cum_qty"]

df[['date', 'time']] = df.transaction_time.str.replace(r'\..*', '').str.split('T', expand=True)

header = ["date","time","symbol","qty","price","side"]

df.to_csv('export_daily_journal_export.csv', columns = header, index = False)
print('')
print('=====Export Completed=====')
```

This is what a single call looks like with the original timestamping

```
    "activity_type": "FILL",
    "transaction_time": "2021-03-22T17:52:28.588182Z",
    "type": "fill",
    "price": "12.65",
    "qty": "29413",
    "side": "buy",
    "symbol": "WKEY",
    "leaves_qty": "0",
    "cum_qty": "29413"
```

It works great but I found one issue with regards to the transaction_time. When exported and massaged it is providing me a time like 19:44:23 when in reality the trade actually occurred at 15:44:23.

```
2021-03-22  17:52:28    WKEY    29413   12.65   buy
2021-03-22  18:29:16    YVR 3061    3.94    buy
2021-03-22  18:29:56    YVR 512 3.92    buy
2021-03-22  18:29:56    YVR 806 3.92    buy
2021-03-22  18:29:57    YVR 1682    3.92    buy
2021-03-22  19:44:14    YVR 6061    4.31    sell
2021-03-22  19:44:23    WKEY    29413   12.6    sell
```

This is based on the data time code and I am unsure of how to update it accordingly. to instead export all transaction times properly OR 4 hours earlier.

Comment: Maybe you have Universal Timezone Issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002158/how-to-set-time-zone-of-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Please show what the data looks like before transformation

Comment: 2021-03-22T17:52:28.588182Z

Answer (score 0):

1.If Series `s` is not a datetime `datetime` type, Conversion type:

```
df.at["s"] = pd.to_datetime(df.s)
```

2.Subtract Timedelta:

```
df.at["transaction_time"] = df["transaction_time"] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=4*60*60)
```