# TypeError occurs when plotting timezone-aware datetimes, loaded via pd.read_csv, with mpf.plot

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror, yahoo-finance, mplfinance

I have stock data that I wanted to play with, and i figured I'd plot it with mpl. This is what I tried:

```
daily = pd.read_csv('data/AAPL/history.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
mpf.plot(daily)
```

This returns

```
TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex
```

Then I tried this, following the [docs](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#usage)

```
daily = pd.read_csv('data/AAPL/history.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
daily.index.name = 'Date'
mpf.plot(daily)
```

This gives the same error.

Then I tried setting the index:

```
daily = pd.read_csv('data/AAPL/history.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
daily.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(daily['Date'])
mpf.plot(daily)
```

With the error:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Trying to do the same but without setting the index:

```
daily = pd.read_csv('data/AAPL/history.csv')
daily.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(daily['Date'])
mpf.plot(daily)
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: [datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
 datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
 datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000)) ...
 datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
 datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
 datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))]
```

This leads me to believe that one of the rows is not formatted correctly. I got this data off yfinance and I'm just reading it in like you'd expect. But since the number of rows is so large (10,823), I'm a little confused on how to clean the dates, on how to find the bad row, if there is any.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know if it's my code or if it's my data. I'm led to believe it's my data, but this is my first time messing with this stuff so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

- The issue can be resolved by formatting the `'Datetime'` column after loading the csv.

  1. `df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col='Datetime')`
  2. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)`

  - `Timestamp('2023-01-03 14:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')` is the resulting format, which does work with `mpf.plot(df)`
- When the data is downloaded from [yfinance](/questions/tagged/yfinance), the index values are as such:

  - `Timestamp('2023-01-03 09:30:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')`, which works with `mpf.plot(df)`.
- `df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col='Datetime', parse_dates=['Datetime'])` results in:

  - `Timestamp('2023-01-03 09:30:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')`, which does not work with `mpf.plot(df)`.
- `mpf.plot(df)` seems to be particular about the timezone, `tz`, format.
- Other options for dealing with timezones in pandas.

  - [How to set time zone of values in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14002158/7758804)
  - [How to remove timezone from a Timestamp column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49198068/7758804)
- **Tested in `python v3.12.0`, `pandas v2.1.2`, `mplfinance v0.12.9b7`, `yfinance v0.2.31`, `matplotlib v3.8.1`.**

#### Load Data from `yfinace` and Plot - Works

- `Timestamp('2023-01-03 09:30:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')`

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf  # conda install -c conda-forge yfinance
import mplfinance as mpf  # conda install -c conda-forge mplfinance

# download data from yfinance
tickers = ['aapl']  # this can contain multiple tickers
df = pd.concat((yf.download(ticker, start='2023-01-01', end='2023-11-14', interval='1h').assign(tkr=ticker) for ticker in tickers), ignore_index=False)

# save the dataframe
df.to_csv('aapl.csv')

# plotting works
mpf.plot(df, type='line')
```

#### Load csv and Parse Dates - Plotting Doesn't Work

- `Timestamp('2023-01-03 09:30:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')`
- Results in `TypeError: Expect data.index as DatetimeIndex`

```py
# load the dataframe and parse dates
df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col='Datetime', parse_dates=['Datetime'])

# plotting does not work
mpf.plot(df, type='line')
```

#### Load csv then Parse Dates with `utc=True` and Plot - Works

- `Timestamp('2023-01-03 14:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')`

```py
# load the file, but don't parse dates
df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col='Datetime'

# set datetime format as utc
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)

# plotting works
mpf.plot(df, type='line')
```

[image]

---

- Note that using `mpf.plot()` sets a particular `style` with `matplotlib rcParams`, which doesn't revert until the notebook environment has changed.
- Plotting also works by directly using `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.

  - However, the other `mplfinance` features can't be used.

```py
# load csv and parse the dates
df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', index_col='Datetime', parse_dates=['Datetime'])

# plotting with pandas works with this format, while it doesn't with mpf.plot
ax = df.plot(y='Close')
```

- Note the plot style is like `mpf.plot`

[image]

- Standard `pandas.DataFrame.plot` format

[image]